# windows file explorer window keeps getting smaller

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I usually open a new file explorer window using `Win`+`E` key on my keyboard. a few months ago the file explorer opens at the size of about half my screen, but then it keeps getting smaller and smaller so now after I open a new file explorer window I need to manually maximize it by clicking on the square symbol on the top right corner.

how do I make the file explorer window automatically as big as it used to be? I use windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: You can try moving the window to a location and resizing it to what you want, then hold CTRL down and press the close button. This will tell windows to store those dimensions and location somewhere in the registry and it will attempt to open the window in that location. Works with many, but not all programs.

Comment: thanks @LPChip worked like a charm. could you put it as an answer instead of a comment so I can vote it as the Correct Answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try moving the window to a location and resizing it to what you want,
then hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> down and click the close button.

This will tell Windows to store those dimensions and location somewhere in the registry and it will attempt to open the window in that location.

Works with many, but not all programs.

Comment: I just found that this solution only seems to work temporarily.. after I restart my computer, it returns to the previous behavior. is there any way to make the fix to work permanently?

Comment: It should stick, so maybe something else is going wrong that sets the position of the window wrong. Do you have it set to start at windows launch by any chance?

Comment: do I have what set to start at windows launch? I only did the Ctrl+click on Close button.. should I edit something in the registry too?